# Finding the inverse of a function.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}_+$ with $f\geq\epsilon>0$ be smooth and define $G:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ thus $$G(x):=\int_0^x\frac{1}{f(u)}\mathrm{d}u$$

Then it is clear that $G$ is well-defined, continuous and strictly increasing (so bijective). Therefore $G$ must have a continuous inverse. What I would like is a formula for the inverse, but I can't seem to come up with one.

Suppose the inverse is given by  $P$, then $G(P(x))=x$ differentiating both sides $$G'(P(x))P'(x)=1$$ hence $$P'(x)=f(P(x))$$ using the fact that $G'=\frac{1}{f}$. So I have an ODE that $P$ would solve ($P$ is continuously differentiable by the inverse function theorem), but it doesn't seem to help!

EDIT in light of the comment: This problem arose in an approximation scheme for stochastic differential equations on manifolds; I don't really know how to explain the background succinctly, but I have imposed no conditions on f beyond what's mentioned above. If anyone knows how to solve the problem in less generality, I would also be very happy.

Comment: How did you arrive at this problem? I feel like this might not be specific enough to allow for a general answer.

Comment: I don't think there is a formula for $P$ in terms of $f$. You can find differential equations and integral equations satisfied by $P$, and you can probably use these to give some kind of an iterative system that converges to $P$. This is like showing that a solutions to an (say, algebraic) equation is unique but being unable to write a formula for the solution.

Comment: All I've got is this: $$\int \frac{dP(x)}{f(P(x))} = x$$ Unless there is explicit knowledge of $f(x)$, there is nothing more to be said, I think.

Comment: Example: Function $\ln x$ can be defined very nicely in terms of an integral, but that doesn't mean its inverse $\exp x$ can be.

Comment: As a general comment which is not addressed to your specific example, I'll say that from a mathematical perspective one accepts the Inverse Function Theorem as a powerful tool for proving existence of inverse functions (and continuous differentiability thereof) without worrying about having a specific formula. Indeed, the inverse function notation $G^{-1}(x)$ is pervasive throughout mathematics even when little is known explicitly about that function. For example, we don't have any "formula" for inverse trig functions other than the notation $\cos^{-1}(x)$ etc.

Comment: We have the differential equation and series for all inverse trig functions, may be not single valued.

Comment: As another approach to why a general formula is unlikely (or at least unlikely to be helpful), suppose we know $f$ is analytic, and use Taylor expansion to write the ODE as $P' = \sum_n \frac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!}P^n$. Then the most we could hope for, closed-form or otherwise, is what is known for arbitrarily nasty nonlinear ODEs. At the very least, we should require that $f$ has sparse coefficients with respect to some basis for which an ODE solution would be tenable.